# Use datefield year as condition in Entity Query

Tags: 8, database

I'm performing an entity query that searches for nodes of my custom content type called 'news'.
The content type has a date field called 'field_date'. I want to be able to perform the query in a way that only produces the 'news' nodes that have a 'field_date' that fits within a specified year. Here is an attempt I made below.

```
$year = 2015;
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->sort('field_date', 'DESC')
  ->condition('type', 'news')
  ->condition('field_date', [date('Y','field_date'), $year], '=')
  ->range(0, 10);
```

In the code above I'm attempting to only grab the year from the 'field_date' datefield and compare that to $year, 2015 in this case. However I receive SQL errors like:

> Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match
>   number of tokens

I'm guessing part of it is date('Y','field_date') doesn't know what 'field_date' is but I'm not sure how to go about it.

How do I make a year comparison on a datefield in a entityquery condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the data in the database looks like this: "2015-10-12T21:30:00", you can use a like query

```
->condition('field_date', $year . '%', 'like')
```

Your code revised with the change:

```
$year = 2015;
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->sort('field_date', 'DESC')
  ->condition('type', 'news')
  ->condition('field_date', $year . '%', 'like')
  ->range(0, 10);
```

Comment: Awesome worked. But I had to change fieldCondition to condition.

Comment: oops, that's correct, updated.

Comment: This is pretty inefficient, you're treating dates as text and running a full table scan. Dates are stored as either `DATETIME_DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT` or `DATETIME_DATE_STORAGE_FORMAT` (see datetime.module) and both of those have been designed so that they sort numerically, and the column is indexed, so you can build a `new DateTime('2015-0-0...')` - i.e. first second of the year - and just compare `$mydt->format('DATETIME_DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT')` to the column with a more than query. Add a "less than last second of 2015" condition and you've got "in 2015".